# Why there is a need of cast in the following program?

Tags: c, casting

Posted the whole code(if needed)

```
 /* multiplication of n1 and n2*/

#include<stdio.h>

int arr[200]; //for storing the binary representation of n2
int k=0; // to keep the count of the no of digits in the binary representation

void bin(int n)
{
   if(n>1)
      bin(n/2);
   arr[k++]=n%2;
}

int main()
{
    int n1=1500000;
    int n2=10000000;

    int i=0,t=0;

    long long int temp,pro=0;

    bin(n2);  // calculating the binary of n2 and stroring in 'arr'

    for(i=k-1; i>=0 ;i--)
    {
         temp = (n1*arr[i]) << t;  /* Why need cast here ? */
         pro = pro + temp;
         t++;
    }
    printf("product: %lld",pro);
    return 0;
}
```

In the above program, I am not getting the desired output. But when I do this:

`temp = (n1*(long long int)arr[i]) << t;`,

then I am getting the correct output !

I am not able to understand the above behavior ?

Comment: Because the result of multiplication seems to overflow, so you need something bigger to store it

Comment: You could also show wrong and correct output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

n1, as well as arr[i], are integers. Without the cast, you get an integer multiplication (which may overflow), shift that integer left (again producing an integer result that may overflow), then assign that integer to temp.

If you cast arr[i] to long long, all calculations are done in long. So, if your integers are 32 bit (and thus limited to about 2e10), your integers will overflow, but the long longs, which should be 64 bit, will not.

Answer (score 3):

It seems likely that on your system `int` is 32 bits and `long long int` is 64 bits.

`n1` and `arr[i]` are both `int`, and result of multiplication is then `int`. But there is not enough bits in `int` to hold the answer because it is too big.

When you cast one member of the operation to `long long int`, then result will also be `long long int` too.

Comment: The above behavior is due to the fact that there may be a greater left shift which is going out of the bound of the 32 bit int ?

Comment: @KaustavRay Not exatly sure what you mean, but whenever you multiple integer type with the same integer type, result may not always fit to same integer type. For example; `INT_MAX * INT_MAX` will overflow, because result will not fit to `int`.

Answer (score 2):

a multiplication between two integer goes into an integer unless you cast one of them to something else. So in the first multiplication the result is stored into an integer (32 bit signed on a 32 bit system), in the second case into a long long (64 bit unsigned on a 32 bit system). You may prefer using types like `int64_t` to have better portability.
You can use `sizeof(int)`, `sizeof(long long)` to see the difference between the two.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that an `int` isn't large enough to store the result of `(n1*arr[i])`, so casting to a `(long long int)` gives enough room to store the result.

`int` Not smaller than short. At least 16 bits.

`long long int` Not smaller than long. At least 64 bits.

Have a look at [C++ Data Types](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/).